# Basic Auth being applied to both route groups

Tags: routes, basic-authentication, laravel-5.6

Here is a mockup of my routing code:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'account',
], function () {
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'basicAuth',
    ], function () {
        Route::post('profile', 'Account\AccountController@profile');
    });
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'browse'], function () {
    Route::post('catalogue', 'Browsing\BrowsingController@catalogue');
});
```

`Kernel.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        // Removed code not relevant to problem
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        // Removed code not relevant to problem
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'basicAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\BasicAuth::class
    ];
}
```

Both `./account/profile` and `./browse/catalogue` only work when Basic Auth user credentials have been supplied, even though only `account` has Basic Auth specified.

How can I get Basic Auth to apply to just one of the routing groups?

Comment: Where is your middleware registered in kernel.php?

Comment: @Devon I've added `Kernel.php`. Let me know if you need to see anything I've removed.